# BigQuery, SQL update command, Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am running the following command:

```
#standardSQL
  UPDATE `speedy-emissary-167213.pgp_orielresearch.pgp_PIK3CA_all_features_values_step_5` AS t2 
 SET 
  chr3_3308581_TGGGGT=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3308581_TGGGGT",1,0),
  chr3_3294651_CA=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3294651_CA",1,0),
  chr3_3300867_CC=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3300867_CC",1,0),
  chr3_3308373_ACTTGACTTG=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3308373_ACTTGACTTG",1,0),
  chr3_3309125__T=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3309125__T",1,0),
......
  chr3_3300985_TT=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3300985_TT",1,0),
  chr3_3308139_AC=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3308139_AC",1,0)
FROM
  `speedy-emissary-167213.pgp_orielresearch.pgp_PIK3CA_all_features_values_step_4_sorted_500` AS t1
WHERE
  t1.sample_id = t2.sample_id
```

When i run it with 500 "chr3_3308581_TGGGGT=IF(t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3308581_TGGGGT",1,0),"  for different columns, the Scalar subquery produced more than one element is fired. when i run it with less command (by deleting part of it), the command runs successfully. what would be the easiest way to debug this query?

Thanks!

Comment: The error seems pretty straightforward. That subquery has multiple values returned when you are using it as a boolean expression. You can't evaluate an IF comparison to T/F if you have multiple inputs.

Comment: why multiple values are returned, these types of values: chr3_3308581_**** are unique. could you please elaborate? thanks

Comment: I can't tell you, it's your data and I'm not clairvoyant. Run your query as a select and find out :)

Comment: @eilalan . . . Your code has no scalar subqueries, as far as I can tell.  Either your actual code is different. you are using a view, or BQ is providing an erroneous error message.  If the latter, perhaps it might occur if more than one record in the joined table matches the row being updated.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I added a long response below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

missing another condition at the where clause. this worked

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE
  `speedy-emissary-167213.pgp_orielresearch.pgp_PIK3CA_all_features_values_step_5` AS t2
SET
  chr3_3294687_A = 1
FROM
  `speedy-emissary-167213.pgp_orielresearch.pgp_PIK3CA_all_features_values_step_4_sorted_500` AS t1
WHERE
  t1.sample_id = t2.sample_id and t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3294687_A"
```